# Toggling DisplayMember in a list box in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, listbox

I am trying to toggle the DisplayMember property in a Listbox in C# Windows app, in VS 2010.

I currently have two buttons that change DisplayMember of a ListBox, but would rather have a single button to toggle between the two available.

In one button, I use

```
lstResults.DisplayMember = "Word";
```

In the other I use

```
lstResults.DisplayMember = "Hooks";
```

That works great, but when I try to use

```
If (lstResults.DisplayMember == "Word") 
   lstResults.DisplayMember = "Hooks"; 
else 
   lstResults.DisplayMember = "Word";
```

I've traced it and DisplayMember doesn't respond to the new assignment.  It doesn't get changed in the code. But it does change in the Listbox itself. So I end up with DisplayMember stuck at "Word" in the code, and stuck at "Hooks" in the actual display.

To make things more challenging, the original buttons won't work after this until I delete the ListBox and add it back to the form. I've cleaned and rebuilt with no change.

I've also tried

```
if (lstResults.DisplayMember.Equals("Word"))
```

with no difference.

Comment: Can you show your datasource ? Your code should work completely fine unless there is no Property called `Hooks` or `Word` in the DataSource.

Comment: The datasource consists simply of a WordID, Word (string), Hooks (string). It works unless I try to compare DisplayMember.

Answer (score 0):

Here the Simple Solution .You just need a Button let say button2 and have a Click Handler given below

```
   if (this.button2.Text == "Show ID")
        {
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            button2.Text = "Show Name";
        }
        else
        {

            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ID";
            button2.Text = "Show ID";
        }
```

where comboBox1 is your Combo Box.

Comment: It's not a combo box, but it does work for the listbox.

Comment: please check it its also work with ListBox. 
you are working with winForms or WebForms???

Answer (score 0):

Using Edward Islam's strategy, but there is another issue that locks up the DisplayMember for the ListBox in the same way.
When I attach the event SelectedValueChanged, DisplayMember won't change unless I assign a new datasource to the ListBox.
The listbox uses "Hooks" as the DisplayMember, but the code shows "Word" and I can't change it. What locks the DisplayMember property like this?

```
private void lstResults_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int sIndex = lstResults.SelectedIndex + 1;
    int count = lstResults.Items.Count;
    this.statusCount.Text = String.Format("{0} / {1}", sIndex, count);
    string selection = lstResults.Text;
if (sIndex > 0)
    {
        int value = Hoot.ValueCalc.getValue(selection);
        double probable = Hoot.Probability.getProbable(selection);
        int relativeProbable = Hoot.Probability.getRelProbable(selection);
        this.statusWordStats.Text = String.Format("Raw Score: {0}   Probability: {1} (RP: {2})",
            value, probable.ToString("F4"), relativeProbable.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution to the second, related issue.
I incrementally added all of the statements back until I got to probability (double probable = Hoot.Probability.getProbable(selection);), which involves combinations and lots of memory. Although the method doesn't change the variable passed, I figured memory was affecting the content so I modified the parameter I was passing.

I tried changing

```
string selection = lstResults.Text;
```

to

```
string selection = String.Copy(lstResults.Text);
```

Same issue.

Then I replaced it with

```
    HookSet selector = (HookSet)lstResults.SelectedItem;
    string selection = String.Copy(selector.Word.ToString());
```

The datasource for the listbox is a

```
List<HookSet>
```

That worked.